# DataTables and columnDefs Rendering Data

Tags: javascript, mysql, arrays, datatables

I am using datatables 1.10.19 and I would like to filter data based on the contents of a table cell.

I am using the [columnDefs](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs) option to alter the contents of the returned data.

I am using [this php script](https://github.com/DataTables/DataTablesSrc/blob/master/examples/server_side/scripts/server_processing.php) to retrieve data.

My code is;

```
$('#example').DataTable({
processing : true,
serverSide : true,
ajax: url": '/server_processing.php',
columnDefs: [{
    targets: 5, // row 6 in the html table
    "render": function(data, type, row) {
        if (row[5] == 0) {
            data = 'rejected';
        }
        return data;
    },
}]
});
```

This successfully displays a table, and `rejected` in column 6 when `0` is returned from the database. However datatables won't allows me to filter on the **word** `rejected`. I get `No matching records found`, however I can filter on the integer `0`.

I thought datatables was supposed to filter what was displayed in the table?

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Do you have `serverSide: true` option in your datatable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple, all I had to do was set this;

`serverSide: false`

Answer (score 0):

You have server-side processing mode enabled (`serverSide: true`) which means that you have to perform search yourself on the server-side. This could be done manually or by using helper classes/libraries.

For example, for PHP use SSP helper class (`ssp.class.php`) available in DataTables distribution. For Laravel framework, there is [Laravel DataTables](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables).

DataTables plug-in performs the search for you only in client-side processing mode.

Comment: Oh ok, in your answer you have mentioned `ssp.class.php` - this is exactly what I am using. I'm not using a framework, standard PHP. What must I change in my code in order to achieve the desired result?

Comment: This would require tweaking `ssp.class.php` to allow raw queries or possibly using tweaked [ssp class](https://github.com/emran/ssp). After that I think you need to use SQL clause like `CASE WHEN id=1 THEN 'accepted' WHEN id=2 THEN 'rejected'  ELSE '' END AS title` when preparing results. I will update the answer when I have more time for more details.

Comment: Thanks, that would be much appreciated! I was under the impression that datatables filtered results based on the client side table content? My database returns `1/0` but I'm rendering `approved / rejected`.